# How to differentiate between single digit numbers and multiple digit numbers as chars in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, arithmetic-expressions

So, I am reading input from stdin and I must compute arithmetic from it. For example, I may be given:

```
3+4
4+3
7+9
```

Which would then be put into a char array like this:

```
{3+4;4+3;7+9}
```

I want to create a program that would take this input and return:

```
{7;7;16}
```

Since this is from stdin in C, each element would be of char type.
I have created the following code to deal with arrays like this and return the proper result:

```
char *int2string(int i, char *s)
{
    sprintf(s, "%d", i);
    return s;
}

        bufferlen = strlen(buffer);
        int result;
        for (i = 0; i < bufferlen; i++)
        {
            if (isNumeric(buffer[i]))
            {
                value1 = atoi(&buffer[i]);
                if (buffer[i + 1] == '+')
                {
                    if (isNumeric(buffer[i + 2]))
                    {
                        value2 = atoi(&buffer[i + 2]);
                        result = value1 + value2;
                        printf("This is the result: %d\n", result);
                        int2string(result, &buffer[i]);
                        for (int k = i + 1; k < bufferlen; k++)
                        {
                            buffer[k] = buffer[k + 2];
                        }
                        //bufferlen = bufferlen - 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, my code only works for input that is comprised of one char and returns a value that is only one char. If I were to run this:

```
34+22
```

My code returns the following:

```
This is the result: 26
322;
```

I believe this is occurring because my code is only able to read one char at a time and can't differentiate between single digit numbers and numbers comprised of more than one digit. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using `strtok` or writing an actual grammar for use with a lexer and parser?

Comment: No, it's not really that complicated.

Comment: Try `if (sscanf(s, "%d + %d", &a, &b)==2)` as a test to see if input is an addition.  "I must compute arithmetic" is vague.  How much arithmetic  must be detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, I think, is that you are doing things like

```
value1 = atoi(&buffer[i]);
if (buffer[i + 1] == '+')
    ...
```

In this fragment, the index `i` "points at" the spot in `buffer` where you're currently parsing.  You believe (and correctly so) that `i` "points at" the first of one or more digit characters.  You call `atoi` to convert that/those digit(s) to an actual integer.  All right so far.  But then you test `buffer[i + 1]` to see if there's an operator character after the number.  *That's* where the improper assumption arose, that numbers are always one digit long.  That's what you need to fix in order to correctly handle multi-digit numbers.

The best way to fix this, I'd say, would be to use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.  The most obvious different between `atoi` and `strtol` is that `strtol` tells you how far it went, how many digits it used.  It does this by returning to you a pointer to the first character it didn't use.

This means, though, that to use `strtol` you're going to have to explicitly use pointers.  It will be much easier if you use a pointer

```
char *p;
```

to step through `buffer`, rather than an index `i`.  But then you can say things like

```
char *endp;
value1 = strtol(p, &endp, 10);
p = endp;
if (*p == '+')
    ...
```

The way this works is, `strtol` sets `endp` to point to the first character it didn't use.  That's where you want to continue your parse, so you set `p` to `endp` and proceed.

What actually happens here is that `strtol` accepts a *pointer to a pointer*.  If you're not comfortable working with pointers yet, you may really not be ready to think about pointers to pointers, but trust me, this works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to use this strategy and notify you if I have any success.

Comment: So, I understand how to use strtol. However, I don't really understand how I can iterate through buffer using it? I could perhaps use a while loop, but I don't know what the condition could be.

Comment: @flutterbug98 The basic idea is that you (a) change `int i` to `char *p`, (b) change `for (i = 0; i < bufferlen; i++)` to `for (p = buffer; p < buffer + bufferlen; p++)`,  (c) change all instances of `buffer[i]` to `*p`, and (d) do the thing I mentioned with `p`, `endp`, and `strtol`.  If you have any remaining `buffer[i+1]` you can change them to `*(p+1)` or `p[1]` (similarly for `+2`, etc.). If you still need to run that second loop on `k`, you can do analogous things with `char *p2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` for getting both operator and any-digit number. You can use it as follows:

```
int sum, len;
sscanf(buffer, "%d%n", &sum, &len); // get the first number

int number;
char op;

buffer += len;

// then pattern is: "operation""number"
while(sscanf(buffer, "%c%d", &op, &number) == 2) // while you can scan both operation and number
{
    if (op == '+')
        sum += number;
    else if (op == '-')
        sum -= number;
    ...
}
```

More about sscanf [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm).

Comment: I guess I should clarify, the input is taken from stdin and automatically put into a char array like this: `{3+4;5+4;34+22}` and I must take this array and compute the arithmetic, returning an array like this: `{7;9;56}`

Comment: It does not matter. For each element of char array, perform the solution that I provided.